# Is it dangerous to use dummy packages in Linux?

Tags: linux, repository

**Is it can be** dangerous to use dummy packages in Linux ? For example : I use Mate. By installing app from repo, it gives me information like :

> You app needs this : libgconf2-4 - GNOME configuration database system
>   (dummy package)

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK dummy packages are not inherently dangerous.

They are  used in the official repos to responsibly handle dependencies when [renaming packages](https://wiki.debian.org/RenamingPackages) and probably other valid use cases.